# Can I change the controls?

Tags: prison-architect

I really want to get Prison Architect, but after watching Yogscast Sjin play it I've noticed that he says the scroll wheel and middle mouse button are prominent buttons. I have a trackball that has neither a scroll wheel nor middle mouse button. I don't want to buy a game I won't be able to play.

Is there a way to change the control scheme in the game to avoid the use of these particular controls?

Comment: The game is still alpha phase; beta phase you will probably have better luck with key mappings. You could buy a decent mouse for $20 and never have the issue again, but if you don't want to support the game in its current state there's nothing wrong with waiting until it suits your gaming setup.

Comment: Experimented a bit and discovered some unlabeled bindings. Edited my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 7):

You can use <kbd>WASD</kbd> to scroll the map, <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> to zoom, and <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate items. No middle mouse button or scroll wheel needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> to change the game speed.

As @harbichidian points out in the comments, use <kbd>Space</kbd> to pause/unpause.

Comment: Toggling pause via the keyboard would be great. If anyone knows a key binding for that, please post it.

Comment: Spacebar toggles between pause and your current speed.

Comment: @harbichidian, words cannot express my gratitude.